# Using Hive DML to generate reports that summaries data

Tags: hive, hiveql

Using relevant Hive DML statements and summary functions to generate  reports that summaries the data.

```
year,town,taxi_co2,bus_co2
2013,luton,1,1
2013,manchester,3,2
2013,london,2,1
2014,luton,1,3
2014,london,3,1
2015,luton,4,1
2014,manchester,6,7
2016,london,2,2
2015,luton,4,1
2015,manchester,1,8
2014,london,3,1
2015,luton,3,1
2015,manchester,1,8
2015,london,3,1
2016,luton,6,5
2016,manchester,4,2
2016,london,3,2
2015,luton,4,1
2013,luton,1,2
2015,london,7,8
2013,manchester,3,2
2015,manchester,1,8
2015,london,7,8
```

The result I want is to filter only year 2013. And then show the total Co2 per town and a horizontal total.

```
town, total taxi co2, total bus co2, total (both taxi and bus)
luton, x, x, x
manchester, x, x
london, x, x, x
```

I have tried using HQL below, but I cannot get my head around completing it or whether my HQL is correct or not. But I'm not getting the desired result. :)

```
SELECT town,
sum(taxi_co2) AS Taxi,
sum(bus_co2) AS Bus
FROM <table>
WHERE year == '2013'
GROUP BY town;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT town,
      sum(taxi_co2)              as Taxi,
      sum(bus_co2)               as Bus,
      sum(taxi_co2)+sum(bus_co2) as Total
FROM <table>
WHERE year = '2013'
GROUP BY town;
```

If sum() for some town can be NULL, use `NVL()` to convert to 0:

```
nvl(sum(taxi_co2),0)+nvl(sum(bus_co2),0) as Total
```